# Linux server accessing a background process started at bootup

Tags: background-process, minecraft

before I explain my issue I should mention that I'm relatively new to Linux so please forgive my ignorance.

I'm using an old Dell E10S to act as a dedicated Minecraft server. 
I managed to install Linux and a working Minecraft server
([downloaded here](https://feed-the-beast.com/modpacks/server-files)).

I also was able to get the server to start upon booting the machine
by adding a command into the rc.local file in `/etc/rc.local`.

Inside `rc.local` I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 1m
cd /home/haven/dw-server/
sudo ./start.sh
```

It worked, but now the server is running in the background when I log in via ssh and I can't type in any server commands like I would on Windows.

Does anyone know how I can bring up the server command line when I ssh into my machine?

I already tried the `fg` command.

Comment: There's already plenty of answers here on this.  `fg` only works for jobs started in the current shell.  Starting it in rc.local doesn't make it a background job, it makes it a daemon.  To attach to that, you have to wrap it in a terminal session manager like screen or tmux.  Minecraft really should do this differently.

Comment: Just to clarify, OP: Aside from wanting to make sure the minecraft server starts on boot, you also want to be able to issue commands to the minecraft server from the command line, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need, and should not use, `sudo` in `/etc/rc.local`. Startup scripts run as `root` (UID 0) already.

Second, your script needs to exit, so that the rest of the startup activities can run. Put your server in the background, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/haven/dw-server
nohup bash -c "sleep 1m;./start.sh" >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

This puts the server in the background, turning it into a daemon, discarding output and error messages. It also puts the `sleep 1m` in the background so that startup can resume more promptly.

Comment: Also, please don't run your minecraft server as root. Every time someone runs their minecraft server as root a sysadmin rips the wings off an angel.

Comment: Third, I don't think you're answering the question the OP is *actually asking* although to be fair they're phrasing it poorly, but I think what they want to know is how to me able to access the *minecraft* server console "like they would in windows" and that's a trickier one.